# Sitemap in Laravel application

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, seo, sitemap, bots

I would like to make a sitemap for my website that is made in Laravel framework. Default .htaccess file in Laravel application looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

As far as I know, this .htacces is redirecting every request to index.php. Now what if sitemap.xml file is in root directory and in robots.txt is path to the sitemap? Search engine bot should make request like 'www.example.com/sitemap.xml' to find and read sitemap file, right? But how can bots find this file, when .htaccess is redirecting every request to index.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry. Request is redirected to `index.php` if:

- It's not an existing directory:

  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
- It's not an existing file:

  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`